# How can I adjust the logo in my header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="main-header" style="background: #484747">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 logo-holder">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing"/>
                </a>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

I want to adjust the image as a logo header because whenever i opened it it is really large. please help me center it and responsive in mobiles or smaller gadgets

Comment: Option 1: make the logo image smaller, option 2: since you are using Bootstrap, add `img-responsive` class to image. `col-md-12` will use full width of the browser, consider something smaller like `col-md-3`

Comment: You are a little unclear. Do you want the image to become the background of the header? (unclickable) or do you wish for it to be a link?

Comment: Provide a code that can be reproduced here, so all of us can see the problem and then try yo help, include css also

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 logo-holder">
     <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php">
             <img src="images/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing" class="img-responsive"/>
         </a>
     </div>      
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you want.  If you want to reduce the size of the image in the page.  you should consider reducing the actual image size, to reduce the amount of data being downloaded to the client.  You can tweak this size on you image with CSS

for you html i  would add a css class:

```
<img class="logo-image" src="img/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing"/>
```

and then in my css define this class:

e.g.

```
.logo-image {
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="main-header" style="background: #484747">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 logo-holder">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing"/>
                </a>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

```css
.logo
{
width:80px;
height:80px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header" style="background: #484747">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 logo-holder">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing"/>
                </a>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use bootstrap, you can add text-center in your div logo

```
<div class="main-header" style="background: #484747">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 logo-holder" style="background: red">
            <div class="logo text-center">
                <a href="index.php">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="elevensixnine clothing"/>
                </a>
            </div>      
        </div>
```